# Can a Helm values.yaml file be Updated from the Command Line?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I'm using gitlab for my build pipeline and helm to package my application.

When the build for my app succeeds I want to update my chart repo with a new image tag.

Is there a way to update the values.yaml file for a helm chart from the helm cli?

Comment: Not helm cli, but I'm working on a tool - Reliza CLI that supports this in various combinations - https://github.com/relizaio/reliza-cli#72-use-case-replace-tags-on-deployment-templates-to-inject-correct-artifacts-for-gitops-using-instance-and-revision - and below. Generally assumed to be used with Reliza Hub SaaS, but you can also pass in --tagsource file parameter to use standalone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `yq` to update the files, but helm does not do this.
I use this to update the version in my chart.yaml

```
yq  -i eval '.version = "${nextVersion}"' Chart.yaml
```

Comment: Be aware that `yq` has a bug where it will remove all blank lines in the YAML file.

https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/515